# Make one layer to not rotate with map

Tags: openlayers-3

I have layer with pictures, I want them to stay as they are and don't rotate with map when I call map.getView().setRotation(x) . There is option to disable rotation for map, but is it possible to disable rotation for one layer?

Answer (score 1):

If your "layer with pictures" is a vector layer with icon images, the icons won't rotate by default. You can control rotation of icons by configuring the icon style with the `rotateWithView` option. The default is `false`. Make sure you don't have a style like this:

```js
new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    src: 'data/image.png',
    rotateWithView: true
  })
});
```

If you do, just remove the `rotateWithView: true` line.

If your layer is a WMS layer, and your images are point styles, you may be lucky to have a WMS server that supports rotation. Then you can add a vendor option (`ANGLE` for GeoServer and MapServer) and update that whenever the view rotation changes:

```js
map.getView().on('change:rotation', function() {
  wmsLayer.getSource().updateParams({
    ANGLE: map.getView().getRotation() / Math.PI * 180
});
```

The above snippet assumes that `map` is your `ol.Map` instance and `wmsLayer` is your `ol.layer.Image` instance with an `ol.source.ImageWMS`.

Comment: I have ol.layer.Image with source ol.source.ImageWMS

Comment: I edited my answer to explain how this could work with WMS, depending on which WMS server you're using.

Comment: I don't have that support

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't disable rotation for one layer. As suggests the answer from @ahocevar the best practice should be to display your "pictures" in a separate vector layer and use the `rotateWithView` options in the style definition of this layer.